# R Function to Replace SPEDIS in SAS

Tags: r, name-matching

SPEDIS Function in SAS calculates cost as follows (Example):

Example

```
data words;
input Operation $ Query $ Keyword $;
Distance = spedis(query,keyword);
Cost = distance * length(query);
datalines;

match       fuzzy        fuzzy
singlet     fuzy         fuzzy
doublet     fuuzzy       fuzzy
swap        fzuzy        fuzzy
truncate    fuzz         fuzzy
append      fuzzys       fuzzy
delete      fzzy         fuzzy
insert      fluzzy       fuzzy
replace     fizzy        fuzzy
firstdel    uzzy         fuzzy
firstins    pfuzzy       fuzzy
firstrep    wuzzy        fuzzy
several     floozy       fuzzy
;
proc print data = words;
run;
```

[image]

I am looking for R function which does exactly same thing. Need Help.

Comment: Package [stringdist](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringdist/) might be of interest to you. The stringdist function will get you far but not exactly the same as SPEDIS as the costs specified in SAS' SPEDIS are somewhat specific.

Comment: But this function again uses levenshtein method to calculate the distance. Also, you cannot use it to compare two columns